# Style an element using the order of its class name appearance in the DOM hierarchy using css only

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible, using **css** only, to set a value of an element property using its rendering order in DOM within the same class name.

Example for making the question more clear:

Assuming I have a class named `demo` and I am willing to render two elements with `demo` as their class:

```
<div id="first" class="demo"></div>
<div id="second" class="demo"></div>
```

Now, in my `.css` file `demo` is defined:

```
.demo{
    font-size: 10px
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the `div` with the id `first` will have `font-size` of `10px` and the `div` with the id `second` will have `font-size` of `20px`. And every other `div` that is dynamically rendered afterwards with the same class name `demo`, will have `font-size` of `calc(10*appearnceNumber)+'px'`. (`id=first` `div` is the first element of class `demo` so `appearnceNumber` will be 1 and the `font-size` will be `10px`).

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: will they be consecutive elements?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think I can arrange them in a way that they will be.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is limited you can approximate like below:

```css
:root {
  --base:10px;
}
.demo {
  font-size:var(--base);
}
.demo ~ .demo {
  font-size:calc(2*var(--base));
}
.demo ~ .demo ~ .demo {
  font-size:calc(3*var(--base));
}
.demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo{
  font-size:calc(4*var(--base));
}
.demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo{
  font-size:calc(5*var(--base));
}
.demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo{
  font-size:calc(6*var(--base));
}
.demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo ~ .demo{
  font-size:calc(7*var(--base));
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
<div class="demo">text</div>
```

Comment: My intention was for dynamically unlimited situation. But thanks for the answer!